# Android Java Cryptography Architecture

Tags: java, android, jce

As known [Java crypto provider](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/security/crypto/CryptoSpec.html) require be a signed Jar file for using some algorithms types (Cipher for example) otherwise `java.lang.SecurityException` will be thrown (JCE cannot authenticate the provider).

Does Android require security provider be a signed jar?

I developed a simple provider with dummy cipher and as expected in JVM I received SecurityException but on Android my cipher works corrdectly.

Comment: Q: "Does Android require security provider be a signed jar?" A: " on Android my cipher works correctly". As you already checked yourself, the android JCE implementation does not require the security provider to be signed.

Comment: Yes, but I want to know why. I can not find documentation on this issue.

Comment: Basically, there is no requirement for crypto providers to be signed in the crypto API or any related specification or JSR. Each implementation is therefore free to choose any approach. For example, OpenJDK 6 did not require signature while the Oracle JDK 6 did require it. And Android, strictly speaking, is not even "Java" implementation, so it can choose whatever approach it wants. In addition, even if your Android application depends on a signed jars, it will be repacked into a single DEX and signatures of all individual dependencies will be lost.